# LinkedIn API - My Connections List and A Contact's Connections

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it possible to have API access to the list of connections that you have? As well as those that a specific connection of yours has? Or just get a user list from a search result URL in a CSV or such file?

I have an intriguing idea for a networking app. I can do some of this with just the URL search parameters. A user see *their* mutual connections with another user. A user can see *their* list of direct connections. And can see the second degree connections of *another* user. But these are all search page results.

If someone from #linkedin wants to talk about a feature add, I would be open to that instead.

Comment: Most APIs of this nature no longer provide access to friend/connection lists, as the friend/connection hasn't consented to their name and other info being shared with your app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api states "To retrieve another member's profile, you will need access to the Person ID, *available only via certain limited access APIs* and subject to member privacy settings."

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. Given I can see all of the data as a logged in user, I would think the API would be the same? It would not me (the developer) seeing a user's connection's connections, but rather the user see their own connections' connections. Same as you can today by going to their profile. Just in an API vs webpage

Comment: No, it's not the same. There are lots of things you can do on places like Linked In and Facebook in-browser that aren't in the API.